# How to include libs when exporting jar

Tags: java, eclipse

for minecraft I want to use BoneCP in my project. The problem is that if I export it to a jar-file, the server runtime informs me about missing classes.

How can I include external .jars to get them working in my own .jar?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the needed jar in the classpath of the main program